# How to convert content of .js.rjs to .js.erb in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rjs

I used following lines in my create.js.rjs file. I just copied from internet and worked just fine.

```
page.select("#notice").each { |notice| notice.hide }

page.replace_html('cart', render(@cart))

page[:cart].visual_effect :blind_down if @cart.total_items == 1

page[:current_item].visual_effect :highlight,
                                  :startcolor => "#88ff88",
                                  :endcolor => "#114411"
```

But now I need to use these 2 lines code in create.js.erb file. Syntax for .rjs and .erb are not same. So what would be the code for .erb file for these 2 linces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# js.erb

$("#notice").hide()
$("#cart").html("<%= j render(@cart) %>")
```

**Update:**

Found [this code in book Agile Web Development with Rails](http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot-30/section-26.4.html):

`js.rjs`

```
page[:cart].visual_effect :blind_down if @cart.total_items == 1

page[:current_item].visual_effect :highlight,
                                  :startcolor => "#88ff88",
                                  :endcolor => "#114411"
```

equivalent `js.erb`

```
$('#current_item').css({'background-color':'#88ff88'}).
  animate({'background-color':'#114411'}, 1000);
```

I kind of getting a feeling that the code you're following is discussed in the linked book in a great detail, so I would suggest taking a look at the book.

Comment: well, your code is not showing any error but javascript is not working . Should I put this into script tag?

Comment: Place this in `app/views/carts/create.js.erb`.  This path is based on your `create.js.rjs` in your question, and I'm assuming this is a create template for `carts`.

Comment: Please check this question, I just posted for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755345/javascript-is-not-working-in-rails-app

Comment: @user1670773, did my answer answer this question?

Comment: can't be sure unless my javascript is working but so far it seems okay

Comment: added two more lines. Please check if you can help me with last two lines as well. Thanks anyway