# Javascript is not working in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in my **store.html.erb** file

```
<%= link_to t('.add_html'), 'javascript:void(0);', 
    :class => "line-item", :product => product.id %>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){
        $(".line-item").click(function(){
            var prod = $(this).attr('product');
            $.ajax({
                url:'<%= line_items_url %>',
                data: {product_id: prod},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'script'
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

my **line_items_controller.rb** has this code

```
  def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(store_url) }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
                             :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
                             :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And then my **create.js.erb** file has this code

```
$("#notice").hide()
$("#cart").html("<%= j render(@cart) %>")
```

And my **_cart.html.erb**

```
<% unless cart.line_items.empty? %>
<div class="cart_title"><%= t('.title') %></div>
<table>
  <%= render(cart.line_items) %>
  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <%= button_to t('.checkout'), new_order_path, :method => :get %>
    <%= button_to t('.empty'), cart, :method => :delete,
              :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>

<% end %>
```

Now when I click add to cart button products should be added in the cart and this should show the updated value in the left side of
    page but it is not showing this. But when I refresh the page I see the updated value. That means my javascript is not working. Please
    let me know why my javascript is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your create.js.erb file

```
$("#cart").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)) %>");
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

you have to send the `@cart` as locals in cart partial and defiantly it will update the value dynamically.

Comment: how can I send @cart as locals in the cart partial?

Comment: $("#cart").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'your_controller/ur_pratial', :locals=>{:cart => @cart})).html_safe %>");

Comment: sorry, im asking pretty obvious questions since im new. Should I write something like carts_controller.rb/_cart.html.erb or I should remove the extensions?  also I think your above line should put in the create.js.erb file, right?

Comment: yes and here you do not need to add any further script tag and external javascript.

Comment: i have describe here the dynamically updating of data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737026/how-remote-true-works-in-rails/20737808#20737808